# IMG tag is showing an extra tag?

Tags: html, image, src

I am new to stack overflow. Sorry if i ask a very beginner question. 
My question is my HTML shows

```
<img src="/images/loading.gif" osrc="xyz.jpg" />
```

What does this osrc represents?? 
There is no code which is calling "osrc". Is there any way to swap these links??

Thanks

Comment: maybe someone is storing extra information in the image tag in the osrc attribute.

Comment: It represents nothing in HTML. It is highly unlikely that it exists if there is no code touching it and you didn't put it there manually. I have no idea what you mean by "sway".

Comment: Please provide some code or we cannot answer your question

Comment: Why not kick it out if its `your` html and you believe its not being used?

Comment: Kindly post your html on something like jsfiddle.net so we can see your code. :)

Comment: Also the HTML looks valid does it show anything other than the usual ?

Comment: Are you using http://ckeditor.com/ ???

Comment: well cause src="..LOADING.gif" it looks like there is other code touching it, or it should be. so like this you first show the loading.gif and then with javascript you could replace the src="" with the osrc="", o (may for original) source ...

Comment: @SurjithSM no.. its a joomla module for showing news.

Comment: @caramba how to replace src="" with osrc="" ?? Thanks

Comment: Code showing when we inspect is this.. 
`<img src="/images/loading.gif" osrc="/images/sepoy1.jpg" >`

Comment: ok this is replacing src with osrc after 5sec http://jsfiddle.net/f2MwV/ it depends how you want to use it. if an img has src the browser has to get that img. so if it is a big img, or lets say you have a big img gallery with big images it could make sense to something after the user has seen a few to load the next couple..

Comment: @caramba thanks for the fiddle:) but what exactly is osrc and why is this attached to src tag ?? Thanks again. :)

Comment: @user3231025 u can call it what ever you want osrc, load-src, xxx. it is not a valid attribute for the <img/> tag. But as shown in the fiddle you can use that and as I tried to explain. If you have many images, big images and you write all of them in the src="" the browser of every client loads all images from the server. lets say you have 100 images in a gallery. you could write the src="" in the first 5 images and in all the other you write osrc="" and just a loader in the src="". now if client is watching gallery after he sees image 3 you load next 5 from osrc="" to src=""

Comment: @user3231025 you are welcome! if you want I can put those last comments together as answer, if they are answering your question?